# Accessing values from dictionary using a column(pandas series) as the key and comparing the values with another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, dictionary

I have a dataframe with 2 columns, and a separate dictionary to help verify the values in the columns. Column A is a series of Keys, Column B is supposed to have the correct values associated to the keys. Column C is the output column that I wish to get, with a boolean value after checking if Column A (the key in dict) is able to get the matching value in the corresponding row in Column B.

The dictionary is like this:

`countries_dict = {"ANZ": "apj_anz", "AU":"apj_aus", "NZ":"apj_nzl"}`

Image to show the columns A, B and the desired output column C:

[image]

I've tried the following code, using a helper column to compare the values found using Col A with Col B and put the result bool in Col C.

```
countries_dict = {"ANZ": "apj_anz", "AU":"apj_aus", "NZ":"apj_nzl"}

df["helper"] = df["A"].map(countries_dict)
df["C"] = df["helper"] == df["B"]
```

This however gives me the following error.

```
numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate 37.8 GiB for an array with shape (71187, 71187) and data type object
```

This is perhaps because I have over 70k rows in my dataset, wondering if there are any more memory efficient ways to achieving the result.

Any advice on how to resolve this would be much appreciated!

---

I've resolved the issue myself:

Earlier in the program I was extracting a string from another column (Col E) using regex, and also comparing it with the value of a different col (Col D) to set a boolean value at Col F

```
df['F'] = (df["E"].str.lower()).str.extract(r'-20....(.*?)_') == df["D"]
```

The script started working when I replaced the above with the following:

```
df['F'] = (df['E'].str.lower()).str.extract(r'-20....(.*?)_')
df['F'] = df['F'] == df['D']
```

I still don't know why exactly this happened, but since its working I'd like to close this question. Thanks everyone who answered! Much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
df['C'] = np.where(df.B.eq(df.A.map(countries_dict)), True, False)
```

Output:

```
    A   B       C
0   ANZ apj_anz True
1   ANZ apj_aus False
2   AU  apj_aus True
3   NZ  apj_nzl True
4   ANZ apj_anz True
5   ANZ apj_aus False
6   AU  apj_aus True
7   NZ  apj_nzl True
8   ANZ apj_anz True
9   ANZ apj_aus False
```

This would avoid the creation of the helper column and hence reduce the memory usage.

You could also try converting Column `A` and `B` to categorical column in case the number of distinct elements in these columns are small. This would further reduce the memory consumption and increase the performance.

**Example:**

Created a sample df with 10 distinct values for column A and B.

Before Conversion:

```
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count    Dtype 
---  ------  --------------    ----- 
 0   A       1000000 non-null  object
 1   B       1000000 non-null  object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 22.9+ MB

%%timeit
df['C'] = np.where(df.B.eq(df.A.map(countries_dict)), True, False)

63.6 ms ± 499 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

After converting the columns to category:

```
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count    Dtype   
---  ------  --------------    -----   
 0   A       1000000 non-null  category
 1   B       1000000 non-null  category
dtypes: category(2)
memory usage: 9.5 MB

%%timeit
df['C'] = np.where(df.B.eq(df.A.map(countries_dict)), True, False)

3.07 ms ± 47.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Still getting the same error, is there are more memory efficient way of doing this? Given that I have over 70k rows.

Comment: @RishTogi, what is the datatype for Column A and B  and number of distinct items in these columns ?

Comment: The datatype for A and B are both string, however I've now resolved the problem. It was another line that was perhaps taking up too much memory?


Earlier in the program I was extracting a string from another column using regex, and also comparing it with the value of a different col (Col D) to set a boolean value at Col F 

df['F'] = (df["E"].str.lower()).str.extract(r'-20....(.*?)_') == df["D"]

The script started working when I replaced the above with the following:
df['F'] = (df['E'].str.lower()).str.extract(r'-20....(.*?)_')
df['F'] = df['F'] == df['D']

Comment: ok, It would still help the performance if you can convert them to category, ofcourse if that meets your requirement. Also i suppose `np.where` is faster than  `df['F'] == df['D']` on a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Your codes seems working fine for the small sample data here.  Probably, the problem was owing to your original dataset is large and you were running short of memory during your processing of defining new helper column and other intermediate results.

You can try to reduce the memory usage without defining the helper column as below:

You can map column `A` with `countries_dict`, compare the mapped result is equal to column `B`.  This comparison result (in boolean True/False) can readily be set to new column `C`, as follows:

```
df['C'] = df['A'].map(countries_dict) == df['B']
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

     A        B      C
0  ANZ  apj_anz   True
1  ANZ  apj_aus  False
2   AU  apj_aus   True
3   NZ  apj_nzl   True
4  ANZ  apj_anz   True
5  ANZ  apj_aus  False
6   AU  apj_aus   True
7   NZ  apj_nzl   True
8  ANZ  apj_anz   True
9  ANZ  apj_aus  False
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error, and you are correct I have around 72,000 rows.